# Safebrowsing API Reporting URL Clean but Google Chrome Browser Flags

Tags: google-chrome, safe-browsing

I have lots of servers. Recently few of them were flagged in Google Chrome Browser.

I tested them using Google Safebrowsing API and it is reporting them clean.

```html
#!/bin/bash

IPADDRESS="http://199.217.118.0"
URL="https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=api&key=APIKEY&appver=1.0&pver=3.01&url=$IPADDRESS"
status_api=$(curl --connect-timeout 3 -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "$URL")
echo $status_api
```

So Where is the gap? Chrome show that The URL is not suspicious at the moment but part of address was listed suspicious in past 90 days.

So How can I get the Status Code in Safebrowsing API for URLS which are clean now but they were part of some issue in last 90 days? Moreover Issue just started appearing in Chrome Browser. But Server is alive for last 2 months and Chrome never reported any issue in past.

I also confirmed with my Server Provider and they said there is no network connection between the Server IP and Domains mentioned in Google's message.

The problem is that this is leaving serious impact on website visitors.

The temporary workaround I'm doing now is to Order New IP for server and add it in interfaces. But the New IP is also being flagged by chrome browser after one day.

Comment: Looking at the API docs, I think you can not request historical data.

Comment: Thanks. I have now migrated data to other server to avoid false positive.